# How can I show that $\Bbb{E}(f(X)g(Y)|X)=f(X)\Bbb{E}(g(Y))$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

> I really have some problems in proving the following result.
>
> Let $X,Y$ be two integrable random variables defined in $(\Omega, F, \Bbb{P})$. Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Then show that for any $f,g:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ bounded we have $$\Bbb{E}(f(X)g(Y)|X)=f(X)\Bbb{E}(g(Y))$$

I am really confused because I don't see where to start. So let me tell you what I have. In my opinion we work here in a continuous situation, i.e. we do not have the formulas for discrete conditioning. Therefore I have the following definition/theorem for the conditioning:

> Let $B\subset F$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra. Let $X\in L^1$ be a random variable. Then there exists a unique random variable $\xi\in L^1$ such that $\xi$ is $B$-measurable and for all $B$-measurable and bounded random variables $Z$ we have $$\Bbb{E}(XZ)=\Bbb{E}(\xi Z)~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$Then $\xi$ is called the conditional expectation of $X$ given $B$ and we write $\xi=\Bbb{E}(X|B)$

But now in my opinion this would mean that it is enough to show that $\xi=f(X)\Bbb{E}(g(Y))$ satisfy $(1)$ or am I wrong?

But the problem is that I am not really comfortable with the whole topic and notations thus I wanted to ask if someone could help me.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Since $f(X)$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable we can pull it out of $\mathbb E(f(X)g(Y)|X)$ . Then we only have to show that for $X,Y$ independent it holds that $\mathbb E(g(X)|X)=\mathbb E(g(X))$. This is not hard using the definition.

Comment: Note that since $X,Y$ are independent, $f(X),g(Y)$ are independent as well. Moreover, $f(X)$ is $\sigma(X)$ measurable. Hence, it's enough to prove that, if $X$ is $\mathcal G$ measurable and $Y$ is independent of $\mathcal G$, then $\mathbb E[XY|\mathcal G] = X\mathbb E[Y]$.

Comment: @KurtG. but can maybe someone explain me why I don't need to use the definition I wrote in the question?

Comment: @DominikKutek why do I know that $f(X)$ is $\sigma(X)$ measurable, because I do not have that $f$ is measurable

Comment: If $f$ is not (borel) measurable, then it may happen that $f(X)$ is not a random variable (i.e measurable mapping). Then the question isn't well posed I believe

Comment: @DominikKutek ah I see. Do you know if Kurt G. refers to my given definition in his comment

Comment: Yes, Kurt G. uses the fact which can be proven via your definition, but in my opinion it is exactly something you have to prove here. Precisely, Kurt G. refers to the fact that if $X$ is $\mathcal G$ measurable, then $\mathbb E[XY|\mathcal G] = X \mathbb E[Y|\mathcal G]$. Do you know it already?

Comment: @DominikKutek No so I know that if $X$ is $B$ measurable then $E(X|B)=X$, can you maybe help me?

Comment: @DominikKutek I first want to prove that since $f(X)$ is $\sigma(X)$ measurable, then it can be pulled out. I thought about doing it with my definition but this do not not help me further, because if I take $Z$ $\sigma(X)$ measurable, then I consider $E(f(X)g(Y)Z)$ but how should I rewrite this?

Comment: Intuitively, $E(f(X)g(Y) \mid X = x) = E(f(x)g(Y) \mid X = x) = f(x)E(g(Y) \mid X = x) = f(x)E(g(Y))$, so $E(f(X)g(Y) \mid X) = f(X)E(g(Y))$. All the steps above can be easily made rigorous by applying your definition of conditional expectation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f(X),g(Y)$ are independent and $f(X)$ is $\sigma(X)$ measurable, it is enough to prove that if $X$ is (bounded, due to $f$ being bounded) $\mathcal G$ measurable and $Y$ is (bounded, due to $g$ being bounded) independent of $\mathcal G$, then $\mathbb E[XY|\mathcal G] = X\mathbb E[Y]$ (then, we use this fact with $\mathcal G = \sigma(X)$, $X \to f(X), Y \to g(Y)$)

We'll do it in two steps, firstly we'll prove that if $X$ is (bounded) $\mathcal G$ measurable, then $\mathbb E[XY|\mathcal G] = X \mathbb E[Y|\mathcal G]$, i.e. we can pull  out $\mathcal G$ measurable stuff out of the conditional expectation (this is the part that Kurt. G refers to) and then we'll prove that if $Y$ is (bounded) independent of $\mathcal G$, then $\mathbb E[Y|\mathcal G] = \mathbb E[Y]$.

Take any bounded $\mathcal G$ measurable random variable $Z$. We want to show (1), i.e $\mathbb E[X YZ] = \mathbb E[\xi Z]$, where $\xi = X \mathbb E[Y|\mathcal G]$. But $$ \mathbb E[\xi Z] = \mathbb E[XZ \mathbb E[Y|\mathcal G]] = \mathbb E[XZ Y],$$ where at the last step we used (1) (with bounded, $\mathcal G$ measurable random variable $XZ$, and $\xi = \mathbb E[Y|\mathcal G]$. In other words, we used (1) not for $\mathbb E[XY|\mathcal G]$, but for $\mathbb E[Y|\mathcal G]$). This proves that $\mathbb E[XY|\mathcal G] = X\mathbb E[Y|\mathcal G]$ for bounded $X$ (note that assumption of boundedness of $X$ and $Y$ isn't necessary. It works for integrable $X,Y$ such that $XY \in L_1$ via some sort of dominated convergence theorem).

Next, we need to show that for $Y$ bounded and independent of $\mathcal G$, we have $\mathbb E[Y|\mathcal G] =\mathbb E[Y]$. We proceed similarly, take any bounded, $\mathcal G$ measurable random variable $Z$. We need to prove $\mathbb E[YZ] = \mathbb E[Z \mathbb E[Y]]= \mathbb E[Z]\mathbb E[Y]$. But since $Z$ is $\mathcal G$ measurable and $Y$ is independent of $\mathcal G$, then $Z,Y$ are independent, so in particular uncorrelated, hence $\mathbb E[YZ] = \mathbb E[Y]\mathbb E[Z]$.

Putting those facts together, we can conclude.

Comment: What is this $G$ in your case? Is this a general $\sigma$ algebra

Comment: Yes, general $\sigma-$algebra such that $X$ is $\mathcal G$ measurable (in whole part) and $Y$ is independent of $\mathcal G$ (in the latter part).

Comment: Sorry in the last part there where we get $E(XZY)$ we use $(1)$ for $E(Y|G)$ right? But this means $E(E(Y|G)Z)=E(YZ)$?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb E[ \mathbb E[Y|\mathcal G] Z] = \mathbb E[YZ]$ for any bounded $\mathcal G$ measurable $Z$. But here we use it with $XZ$ instead of $Z$ (we know that $X,Z$ are $\mathcal G$ measurable and bounded, hence $XZ$ is $\mathcal G$ measurable and bounded)

Comment: Ah so you mean we define $Z'=XZ$ and the $E(E(Y|G)Z')=E(YZ')=E(YXZ)$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant

Comment: Okey thanks a lot!

Comment: I will think about the rest and write if there are questions